# Using the laws of logic (algebraic version) to show the following equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

[image: three propositional equivalences]

I have some questions about algebra and discrete, with using law of logic.
I am not sure how to prove the equivalences.

Can someone please show me how this works and show the equivalence using the law of logic?

(b) (p → (q → r)) ≡ (q → (p → r))

(c) ((p → r) ∨ (q → r)) ≡ ((p ∧ q) → r)

Comment: There is at least one error since (a) is false. Take p=T and q=F for a counterexample.

Comment: (c) is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1520153/123905

Comment: (b) follows from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424410 and commutativity of conjunction.

Comment: @MPW (a) is true. In fact, your suggested counterexample leads to $$LHS=\neg(\neg T\wedge F)=\neg F=T\\ RHS = \neg F\rightarrow T=T\rightarrow T=T$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : No, my comment was correct. The question has been edited since I posted the comment. Originally, (a) was "$(p \wedge q) \equiv (q \to p)$". For that, with my suggestion, LHS becomes $T\wedge F$, which is $F$, and RHS becomes $F\to T$, which is $T$.

Comment: @MPW Oh, I see: I did not check for that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply various identities such as DeMorgan's law. Take a look at http://www.csm.ornl.gov/~sheldon/ds/sec1.1.html

You can prove these identities with truth tables and then use the formal approach for efficiency. Let's do (a)

\begin{align}
\overline{\overline p \land q} \equiv \overline{\overline p} \lor \overline q \equiv p \lor \overline q \equiv \overline p \rightarrow \overline q \equiv q \rightarrow p
\end{align}

Where I have used, in order: DeMorgan's law for negation of a conjuction, double negation resolves to identity , then a -> b equivalent to not a or b and finally contrapositive.